# Use custom Role with Authorize attribute

Tags: .net, authorization, middleware, webapi, asp.net-authorization

- I have a custom Authorization Handler, in the custom Authorization handler I am doing such operation

```
    var user = userService.GetUser();
    if (user.Roles.HasRole("DummyRole"))
    {
       context.Success();
       return;
    }
```

- The application is setup to use Auth0
- Currently I am using the Authorization attribute with Policy property such as

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdminRole")]
```

- My service registration is as follows:

options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policyBuilder =>
{
policyBuilder
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
.AddRequirements(new RequireDummyRoleRequirement(Roles.DummyRole))
})

- **What I want to achieve** is to use the custom Role from the Authorize attribute in such way

```
[Authorize(Role = "Admin")]
```

and in the handler

```
    var user = userService.GetUser();
    if (user.Roles.HasRole("AdminRole"))
    {
       context.Success();
       return;
    }
```

Please be aware that the Role is a custom property of the user object I am retrieving from my user service, it is not the Role defined in the identity object.